# NHibernate explicit polymorphism

Tags: nhibernate

My Base class mapping:

```
<class name="BaseClient,BackOffice.Core"  table="client" polymorphism="explicit"  >
<id name="Id" unsaved-value="0" type="int">
  <column name="id" not-null="true"/>
  <generator class="hilo">
    <param name="max_lo">0</param>
    <param name="where">table_name = 'clients'</param>
  </generator>
</id>
<property name="Name" >
  <column name="name" length="1024"/>
</property>
```

Mapping of it's child

```
   <joined-subclass name="Client, Transport.Core" table="transport_client" extends="BaseClient, BackOffice.Core">
    <key column="Id"/>
  </joined-subclass>
```

Mapping class, which contains BaseClient

```
 <class name="BankPayment, BackOffice.Core"  table='bank_payment'>
    <id name="Id" unsaved-value="0" type="int">
      <column name="id" not-null="true"/>
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>    
    <many-to-one name="ClientSource" class="BaseClient,BackOffice.Core" column="client_source_id" cascade="none"/>
```

And now query:

```
ICriteria criteria = NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(BankPayment));
criteria.SetFetchMode(BankPayment.Properties.ClientSource, FetchMode.Join);
```

So i get this sql

```
FROM bank_payment this_ 
left outer join client baseclient2_ on this_.client_source_id=baseclient2_.id 
left outer join transport_client
```

So my question is why I get second sql, and how can I avoid it. I think  explicit polymorphism should help, but I've got second join. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't avoid the join, for a very good reason: since `Client` exists, any reference to a `BaseClient` could be a `Client`.

You specifically asked NHibernate to fetch the `ClientSource`, and the only way to do so is with the join; otherwise it would risk getting an "incomplete" instance.

What the "explicit" polymorphism attribute value does is not related to this; only to queries of that particular type (check the docs for a better description)

Comment: Ok, thanks. And what should I do if I want get "incomplete" instance. BaseClient contains all nesessary data.

Comment: Then your domain model is not correct. You should be using a one-to-one relationship instead of inheritance.